# Check if elements (DOM Nodes) are siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How to check if two DOM elements are siblings?

#### Example DOM structure:

```
<div>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <p></p>
</div>
<i></i>
```

Test if `<b>` is a sibling of `<a>` but not of `<i>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### jQuery:

```
var a = $('a'),
    b = $('b'),
    i = $('i');

a.siblings().is(b); // true (since "b" is sibling of "a")
a.siblings().is(i); // false (since "i" is sibling of "div" and not of "a")
a.siblings().is(a); // false (can't be singling of itself)
```

### Vanilla:

```js
const elm_p = document.querySelector('p');
const elm_a = document.querySelector('a');
const elm_i = document.querySelector('i');

const areSiblings = (elm1, elm2) => 
  elm1 != elm2 && elm1.parentNode == elm2.parentNode;

// tests
[
  [elm_p, elm_a], // true
  [elm_a, elm_p], // true
  [elm_a, elm_a], // false
  [elm_a, elm_i]  // false
].forEach(([a,b]) => console.log(areSiblings(a,b)))
```

```html
<div>
    <a></a>
    <b></b>
    <p></p>
</div>
<i></i>
```

Comment: did you ask this question knowing the answer? You could of altered the question to ask if this way is best.

Comment: @BenG _"You could of altered the question to ask if this way is best."_ What do you mean by "best"?

Comment: best, correct, whatever. The same minute you asked the question. you put this answer. It looks to me you wasn't asking a question. which I dont understand the reasoning.

Comment: @BenG - yes, I do this all the time, for the past 7 years in stackoverflow. I ask a question and write the answer, so others could benefit from it when they go hunting on google for help. helping the community with personal knowledge is very important to do.

Comment: @BenG _"It looks to me you wasn't asking a question. which I dont understand the reasoning"_ See [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992)

Comment: @guest271314 Ahh. I see. after reading the meta I understand. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Since this question is tagged "javascript", would you mind posting a JavaScript solution also?